# How to draw a colored framebox without filling the background?

Tags: color, boxes, framed

I like to draw a `\fbox{..}` which is colored. The `xcolor` package gives

```
\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{<text>}
```

But this forces me to set a background color. I like to have the background not filled at all, but simply the frame drawn in a color. Setting it to the paper color (white normally) would be a workaround but doesn't work for shaded backgrounds.

Is there another macro for this or a possibility to set `<background color>` to transparent or have it ignored?

PS: I like to do this without using anything as big as TikZ or PSTricks. This is actually for use in a package and shouldn't force users to also load these packages.

Comment: Use TikZ. `;-)`

Comment: @Caramdir: TikZ solution is still long: `\tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=red]{hello};`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Would setting the color before a framebox and resetting it to the normal text color inside and after the framebox work for your application?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    {\color{#1}%
    \fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}

\cfbox{red}{In red box} Normal black text

\color{blue} A paragraph with blue text and \cfbox{orange}{some words} in an orange box. 
\end{document}
```

[image: colored framebox]

Comment: Scoping can be used to smooth coding workflow.

Comment: What is the trailing `{}` for? Is it really necessary?

Comment: It was necessary before I incorporated your scoping suggestion =) Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you. I was anticipating such a method but wasn't sure if it works OK with `\fbox` fully correctly. Apparently it does. As a further improvement you can wrap the whole macro content in a `{ }` group to keep the `\colorlet` local. Also I might add an early `\leavevmode` because I twice had issues with `\color` if this wasn't used. However, it seems to be fine here, which is funny. Note that `\textcolor{..}{..}` is basically just `{\leavevmode\color{..} ..}`.

Answer (score 8):

In the meantime I build this functionality into my `adjustbox` package. It is included in v0.5 from 2011/08/07. Simply use the `cfbox=<color>` key which also has more potential arguments as explain in the manual.

You can also define a shortcut macro for it. I'm using here Jake's example text for easier comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}[2011/08/07]

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\cfbox}[1]{%
    \adjustbox{cfbox=#1}%
}

\cfbox{red}{In red box} Normal black text

\color{blue} A paragraph with blue text and \cfbox{orange}{some words} in an orange box. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!20}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{{\color{#1}\fbox{\normalcolor#2}}}
\begin{document}   
\mybox{blue}{Enclosed by a blue box} Return to the normal color
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\normalcolor` wouldn't work in the second example I used in my answer: The text in the framebox wouldn't have the same color as that surrounding it.

Comment: @Jake: Is it  a feature that Martin wants to get? :-) just call `\mybox{<anothercolor>}{\color{<surroundingcolor>}text}` that is a usual behavior adopted by TeX.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with no particular advantage, except if 1) you already have loaded `colortbl` and 2) you don't care that the result is not 100% the same as `fbox`'s.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

text 1
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline text2 \\\hline 
\end{tabular} \fbox{text3} text4 \\
text text text

\end{document}
```

[image: fboxvstabular]